# Local database with SQLite in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I create a test app with a local database in Windows phone 8 but I get error and my project can't create my sqlite database

Can you help me ?

Runtime error is this :

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

In this line : val = m.GetValue( obj , null ) ;

`Person` class :

```
namespace PhoneApp4
{
    public class person
    {
        [SQLite.AutoIncrement , SQLite.PrimaryKey]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`mainpage.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace PhoneApp4
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        private async void BTO_save_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "dbsqlite.sqlite"), true);
            person person = new person
            {
                FullName = TB_save.Text
            };

            await conn.InsertAsync(person);
        }

        private async void BTO_search_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "people.db"), true);

            var query = conn.Table<person>().Where(x => x.ID == Convert.ToInt32(TB_search.Text));
            var result = await query.ToListAsync();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                LB_search.Items.Add(item.ID.ToString() + "    " + item.FullName.ToString());
            }
        }
```

`app.xaml.cs`:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "dbsqlite.sqlite");
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            db.CreateTable<person>();
        }
}

// Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
// This code will not execute when the application is first launched
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "dbsqlite.sqlite");
    if (FileExists("dbsqlite.sqlite").Result)
    {
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            db.CreateTable<person>();
        }
    }
}

// Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
// This code will not execute when the application is closing
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "dbsqlite.sqlite");
    if (!FileExists("dbsqlite.sqlite").Result)
    {
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            db.CreateTable<person>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which SQLite library are you using?

Comment: Can you try this [new tutorial](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/08/windowsphone-8-sqlite-storing-data-in.html) and report back?

Answer (score 0):

See this sample
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLite-for-Windows-Phone-8-8ff3beaf

```
 private async void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("UniversityDB.db"); 
                Connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("UniversityDB.db"); 
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException) 
            { 
                DataService.CreateDbAsync(); 
            } 
        }
```

and

```
public static async void CreateDbAsync() 
        { 
            App.Connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("UniversityDB.db"); 

            var universityTask = App.Connection.CreateTableAsync<University>(); 
            var studentTask = App.Connection.CreateTableAsync<Student>(); 

            await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { universityTask, studentTask }); 
        }
```